# how can i insert data into table by the help of migration and that table is generated previously through another migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a role table with user name and role and company. I want to insert data into that table through a new migration file so how can i do this?

I got a code like this but how can i use it and where i am not able to understand.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Users.new(:username => "Hello", :role => "Admin")
  end
  def self.down
    Users.delete_all(:username => "Hello")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
Users.new(:username => "Hello", :role => "Admin")
```

does not insert data into your table. It merely creates a user object. To insert the data you have to call `save` on the object you create:

```
Users.new(:username => "Hello", :role => "Admin").save
```

Or better yet, use `create` instead of `new`:

```
Users.create(:username => "Hello", :role => "Admin")
```

Comment: where i have to right this code i am confused in that i wanna enter this data through migration in previous generated table

Comment: What do you mean? You already have that code in a migration file, so why are you asking where to write that code? Please explain what the problem is more clearly.

Comment: hello mischa thanks i done this by the help of your answer only actually i was confused but after some google and practical i got this

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are using this database migration solely for populating the data.

Database migrations are meant for changing the database schema, not for populating the database (though you can add some logic to populate the database after the change; for example, if you add a column - role to users table, you can add some custom logic to populate the newly added field for existing entries in users table). Refer to rails api - [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for details.

If you forgot add the code to populate the database in your previous database migration, you can undo the previous migration and apply it again using:

```
rake db:rollback
... Edit the previous migration ..Add the code to populate
rake db:migrate
```

If you just want to populate the database, you should seed the database instead. Watch [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) for more information.

EDIT: To seed the database:

Create a file called db/seeds.rb
Add the record creation code like this:

```
['Sampath', 'Suresh'].each do |name|
  User.create(role: 'admin', username: name)
end
```

Then,

```
rake db:seed
```

This will read the seeds.rb and populate the database.

Comment: Salil i can rollbacke that because its one year old table and i am not allow to touch that table so is there any other way so i can run a new migration and insert data into tables.